# Convert excel to pdf using phpexcel,tcpdf and jpgraph

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel, tcpdf, jpgraph

When converting excel to pdf, **chart** is not reflecting in output pdf file.
Other cell contents are coming like texts and table contents. Image also not rendered.

Below is my code.

```
    require_once 'phpExcel/PHPExcel.php';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $filename = 'sample.xlsx';
    if (PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename) == "Excel2007") {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
        $objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    } else {
        die("Can't load charts");
    }
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
    $rendererLibraryPath = 'tcpdf';
    if(!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer( $rendererName, $rendererLibraryPath ) ) {
        die('NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .'<br />' .'at the top of s script as appropriate for your directory structure');
    }
    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::CHART_RENDERER_JPGRAPH;
    $rendererLibraryPath = 'jpgraph/src';
    if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setChartRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath)) {
        die('NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .EOL .'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure');
    }
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
    $objWriter->writeAllSheets();
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $outputFileName  = 'sample';
    header('Content-type:Application/pdf');
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$outputFileName.".pdf" );
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Is any wrong in my code ? I'm using ubuntu os, libreoffice calc excel.
Thanks in advance.